# How to paraphrase "the next day"?

Tags: synonyms, paraphrasing

I'm writing a text in past tense, and I wish to dexribe it day by day, but writing 'the next day' in the beginning of each sentence seems awful.
Any suggestions?

<sup>Upd: the comments were really useful, if someone sums them up, I'll accept</sup>

Comment: You may say: *the following day.*

Comment: You can also specify the date a bit more: "Thursday", "the 20th of December", etc.

Comment: @Laurel unforunately, the narrative isn't really tied to date, and making year 19XX up just to paraphrase "the next day" seems a bit of an overkill

Comment: @mekkanizer I wouldn't know that without context...

Comment: In the morning, after a good night’s sleep, ...

Comment: Day 1, Monday.  day 2, Tuesday.  day 14, Sunday. day 25, Thursday, day 26, Friday, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From comment suggestions, I found these two:

- The following day
- One day later

Most suitable for the case.
Creating *diary/journal*-like Day 1, Day 2, etc. is also a good approach, but the text I was working on is too small for this *detailed logging*. Each day took a sentence or two.

Comment: @DarshanBaral I'm sorry Darshan, but I find this usage *silly*. I would rather use your phrase to describe consequences of previous day, like, <...> I was exhausted, <...> everything seemed new to her, etc etc. So thx for suggestion but it's unsuitable at all IMO